# Updating the loaded assembly in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, appdomain

After researching, I found the approach for this solution:

- Create new appdomain and load the assembly into new appdomain.
- To update the assembly, unload the appdomain contains that assembly, create other appdomain and load the assembly file with newer version.

But, I have 2 big problems:

1. **File locking**: althought I enabled shadowcopy for the new appdomain and implement the AssemblyResolve event to load the assembly from byte array instead of the real file. I tried to delete the assembly file after reading it to byte array, the application still work fine and I found that: If there is the real assembly file, the deafault domain will refernce to this assembly and lock its file after I call "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" with new appdomain, so I can't delete this file. (In the new appdomain, ApplicationBase is 'bin' folder of default appdomain, AssemblyResolve event load the assembly byte array from 'Plugin' folder outside the 'bin' folder ).
2. **Only one assembly version loaded**: after I try that bad way above to be able to delete the assembly file and replace with another version, the AssemblyResolve event also load the byte array from new file, but the function "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" return the instance of old assembly. I researched on many webpages and I see that ASP.Net load the new assembly in the other domain as domain neutral assembly and can't be unloaded. But I found the article ["Loading and Unloading an Assembly at Runtime"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18729/Loading-and-Unloading-an-Assembly-at-Runtime) that has an example load other assembly version successfully, but it's a desktop application. So I consider the problem in ASP.Net with appdomain.

Is there the best way to resolve these problems!